# Blog host with importing from dotnetnuke blog

Tags: import, dotnetnuke, blogs

I want to migrate my blog from my own dotnetnuke site to another host (like blogger, posterous etc). Do you know any such host that supports importing from dotnetnuke.
Posterous supports importing using MetaWebLog API, which is supposed to be supported by dotnetnuke blog module. I tried it but it does not work. I always get 'We were not able to authenticate this account' message from Posterous, altough at the same time I can post to my dnn blog using Word and MetaWebLog API.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is more suited for http://superuser.com. I have voted to move it there; after five people vote it will move automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I agree about moving this to superuser.com.  In the meantime, here's an answer.

I am a developer on the DNN Blog module team.  I have three answers:

1. You should stay on DNN! :)
2. You really need BlogML support for this to work correctly.  BlogML is coming to the Blog module (timeframe TBD)
3. You may be able to change your RSS settings in the blog module to use RSS to solve this problem.  If you DO NOT use Summaries (but instead let the module create summaries automatically) then if you change these settings in Module Options then all of your content will be served by the RSS feed:

   - Limit Auto-Generated Summaries to: 0
   - RSS Entries to Display: 0

I don't know why the MetaWebLog interface doesn't work for you.  Possibly a compatibility issue between Posterous and the DNN MWL implementation?